# how to delete\get rid of vscode completely?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, installation

I messed up something I don't know while configuring my vscode to be able to connect it to remote host and now I want to delete it and start over. Somehow it retrives the previous settings. Yes I know this issue is widely described here but I followed all the steps specified still I can't get rid of vscode in my pc.

I do control panel> programs> vscode  and I uninstall the program. I also find the app data> roaming> code folder and delete that. I also make sure deleting everything from my rycle bin to make sure. I reinstall the vscode and it still has the previous extentions already installed. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

- You can get rid of the extensions installed in this path `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- it's recommended to delete the entire .vscode folder.